# HighCharts Cloud toggle data table

Tags: button, highcharts, export, cloud, toggle

I've got a bunch of charts showing on a single page via the HighCharts cloud inject code. Because the data for each chart is quite large, the page gets massive if the user selects **View data table** from the menu - which I'm fine with, but I would prefer the user be able to Toggle the table triggered by the same menu button. Is there any way I could do this via the custom code?

I've figure dout how to change the text in the menu to **Toggle data table**, but can't figure out how to apply the toggle code.

This is what I have so far:

```
exporting: {
  buttons: {
    contextButton: {
      enabled: true,
      text: 'Download',
      menuItems: ["printChart",
                "separator",
                "downloadPNG",
                "downloadJPEG",
                "downloadPDF",
                "downloadSVG",
                "separator",
                "downloadCSV",
                "downloadXLS",
                {
                    textKey: 'viewData',
                    text: 'Toggle data table',
                    onclick: function() {
                        this.viewData()
                        }
                }]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Highcharts doesn’t offer any method for hiding the data table. The workaround is to put the following logic in `onclick` event:

```
    onclick: function() {
      if (this.dataTableDiv && this.dataTableDiv.style.display !== 'none') {
        this.dataTableDiv.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        this.viewData();
        this.dataTableDiv.style.display = '';
      }
    }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2t1w4pu9/

Cloud doesn’t include export-data module in its editor but the generated inject-script does. So the functionality works outside the Cloud (e.g. on *jsfiddle*).

Comment: That's brilliant @Kamil - just what I'm after :)